# F#: Downcast seq to IEnumerator

Tags: f#, ienumerator, seq

Why is it that in F#, I can do this...

```
let s = seq { for i in 0 .. 4095 do yield i } :?> IEnumerator
```

... but this throws a `System.InvalidCastException`?

```
let s = Seq.init 4095 (fun i -> i) :?> IEnumerator
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want IEnumerable rather than IEnumerator?

Comment: I'm writing a coroutine for Unity.  Has to be IEnumerator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A sequence expression creates an object that implements  `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>`

```
let s = seq { for i in 0 .. 4095 do yield i }
printfn "%b" (s :? IEnumerable<int>) // true
printfn "%b" (s :? IEnumerator<int>) // true
```

But `Seq.init` does not:

```
let s = Seq.init 4095 (fun i -> i)
printfn "%b" (s :? IEnumerable<int>) // true
printfn "%b" (s :? IEnumerator<int>) // false
```

You could refactor your code to use `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IEnumerator` since both constructs produce an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Alternatively, if you really want an `IEnumerator`, you could simply call `GetEnumerator` to return an `Enumerator` from an `Enumerable`:

```
let s = (Seq.init 4095 (fun i -> i)).GetEnumerator()
printfn "%b" (s :? IEnumerable<int>) // false
printfn "%b" (s :? IEnumerator<int>) // true
```

Comment: Dang, stole my answer. Well, part of it... Didn't know that sequence expressions don't produce quite the same thing as their Seq module counterparts, though.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at [the specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818836), you sequence expression is converted to:

```
Seq.collect (fun pat -> Seq.singleton(pat)) (0 .. 4095)
```

if you look at the source for the definition of `Seq.collect` it is:

```
let collect f sources = map f sources |> concat
```

and if you look at the definition for `concat` it is:

```
let concat sources = 
            checkNonNull "sources" sources
            mkConcatSeq sources
```

`mkConcatSeq` is defined as:

```
let mkConcatSeq (sources: seq<'U :> seq<'T>>) = 
            mkSeq (fun () -> new ConcatEnumerator<_,_>(sources) :> IEnumerator<'T>)
```

so you can see that the returned sequence implements `IEnumerator<'T>` and therefore `IEnumerator`.

Now `Seq.init` is defined as:

```
let init count f =
            if count < 0 then invalidArg "count" (SR.GetString(SR.inputMustBeNonNegative))
            mkSeq (fun () -> IEnumerator.upto (Some (count-1)) f)
```

and `mkSeq` is defined as:

```
let mkSeq f = 
            { new IEnumerable<'U> with 
                member x.GetEnumerator() = f()
              interface IEnumerable with 
                member x.GetEnumerator() = (f() :> IEnumerator) }
```

so it only implements `IEnumerable<'T>` and not `IEnumerator`.